# a cross polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Consider $2n$ positive numbers $a_{i}$ and define the set $S=\prod_{i=1}^{n}[-a_i,a_{i+n}]\subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ We pick one point $x_i$ from the interior of each facet ($n-1$-dimentional face) of S. Does the convex hull of the set $\{x_i\}_i$ has non-empty interior as subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? (an $n$-dimensional convex set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.

Imagine our old 3D cube and cut it with a plane passing through the center and perpendicular to a great diagonal. It will pass through all six faces. Pick your points somewhere within this section, and their convex hull will obviously be planar as well.

I guess this generalizes naturally to higher dimensions.

Comment: Nice intuition (+1)...  
what about $R^n$ with $n$ even number and $n >2$?

Comment: Even or odd, it doesn't matter. The hyperplane $x_1+\dots+x_n={n\over2}$ will cut through all facets anyway.

Comment: what is the center of your cube? origin?

Comment: Nope, my cube is $[0,1]^n$.